# jQuery/PHP session management by URL (or just specific serialization?)

Tags: php, jquery, session, serialization, persistence

My application is JavaScript and jQuery up front, PHP in the back.  I'd like to implement a URL- or parameter-based session management system so my users can save/share their results.  Most of the solutions I've seen involve cookies, but I want anyone (e.g. anyone my user gives a link to) to be able to open up exactly where the user left off.

Example:

1. User A goes to www.my.url and interacts with the page.  Variables are set (mostly via jQuery) et al.  User A then decides he wants to share what he sees with user B.  He clicks a button and is issued a URL.
2. User B gets the link from user A and goes to www.my.url?session=[randomness] or www.my.url/?[randomness] (either would be okay).  User B picks up exactly where User A pressed the button to issue the link.  User B continues to interact with the page.
3. User A goes to the same URL and picks up where he pressed the button.  He then interacts with the page.  User A's and user B's sessions do not share anything and the actions of one do not have any bearing on the other - each "real" user session is strictly a sandbox again after the URL is passed and delivered.
4. User A and B both go to www.my.url (without a session identifier) and get the 'factory' startup as User C does.

Also none of these user actions have to (or probably will) happen concurrently.  I can use file-based or mySQL for session (and content) serialization.  Currently using CSV for 'factory' reference data (search base) and no need to jump to a DB.

Does anyone know of a practical all-up example here? Or a set of tutorials to help me get started?  Is 'session management' really what I'm asking for or is it just serialization via URL(ish)?  Is there a better way to search/ask for what I need?

Thank you, any help is appreciated here as this shareable aspect will be huge for my application.

Comment: I think none - I'm mostly concerned about capturing a couple of arrays which exist in JavaScript.  If I can record those, I can feed them back to my app when the URL is accessed and make the display 'look' like it did for User A.  Nothing about what User A does before or after the URL button-press is important.

Comment: No, not huge, at most a couple dozen elements per.  Is there a plugin out there that will serialize and bind to a URL?